# I want to set the index name by the time value in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

my configuration

```
input {
 http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => "18080"
    codec => es_bulk {
    }
    type => "http"
  }
  heartbeat {
    interval => 10
    type => "heartbeat"
  }
}

output {
  if [type] == "heartbeat" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "1.2.3.4:9200"
      index  => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" <-- error
      index  => "logstash" <-- not error
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "1.2.3.4:9200"
      index => "%{[@metadata][_index]}"
      document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
      template_name => "%{[@metadata][_template]}"
    }
  }

  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug {
      metadata => true
    }
  }
}
```

At the same time, I want to receive "input-http" and "heartbeat".
An error occurs when the index name is inserted in the form of time.

What's wrong?

error log

```
[2017-09-06T18:49:14,759][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed to install template. {:message=>"Malformed escape pair at index 11: /_template/%{[@metadata][_template]}", :class=>"Java::JavaNet::URISyntaxException", :backtrace=>["java.net.URI$Parser.fail(java/net/URI.java:2848)", "java.net.URI$Parser.scanEscape(java/net/URI.java:2978)", "java.net.URI$Parser.scan(java/net/URI.java:3001)", "java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(java/net/URI.java:3019)", "java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(java/net/URI.java:3105)", "java.net.URI$Parser.parse(java/net/URI.java:3063)", "java.net.URI.<init>(java/net/URI.java:588)", "java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java/lang/reflect/Constructor.java:423)", "RUBY.format_url(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:96)", "RUBY.perform_request(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:67)", "RUBY.perform_request_to_url(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:269)", "RUBY.perform_request(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:257)", "RUBY.with_connection(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:347)", "RUBY.perform_request(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:256)", "RUBY.head(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:264)", "RUBY.template_exists?(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:318)", "RUBY.template_install(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:78)", "RUBY.install(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:29)", "RUBY.install_template(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:9)", "RUBY.install_template(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:62)", "RUBY.register(/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:29)", "RUBY.register(/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:9)", "RUBY.register(/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:41)", "RUBY.register_plugin(/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:268)", "RUBY.register_plugins(/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:279)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)", "RUBY.register_plugins(/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:279)", "RUBY.start_workers(/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:288)", "RUBY.run(/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:214)", "RUBY.start_pipeline(/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:398)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)"]}
[2017-09-06T18:49:14,837][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<LogStash::Error: timestamp field is missing>, :backtrace=>["org/logstash/ext/JrubyEventExtLibrary.java:202:in `sprintf'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:173:in `event_action_params'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:48:in `event_action_tuple'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:42:in `multi_receive'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2414:in `map'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-7.3.5-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:42:in `multi_receive'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:13:in `multi_receive'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:47:in `multi_receive'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:407:in `output_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:406:in `output_batch'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:352:in `worker_loop'", "/home1/user/apps/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:317:in `start_workers'"]}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error that you are seeing.

Comment: @Animesh append a log.

Comment: The error is telling you that your data doesn't contain a timestamp field.  If it does, you need to use the `date` filter to parse it (which will then set `@timestamp`).

Comment: @Alcanzar Does it have nothing to do with the index name? When you did this, it worked out. ["logstash"], Attaching a time value after the index name caused an error. ["logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"]

Comment: because you have the "time sprintf" -- the `%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`, logstash needs to know the time of the event